# correlated subquery pattern not supported error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table something like this:

[image: Table here]

You can notice that there are many values in serp_flag column as null. I need to fill those fields. It has to be filled with previous non null value. so, if my last non null value is 1, then all null fields after that should be 1 unless a non null field comes. Similarly, if last non null value was 0 then all null fields after that should be 0. This table has millions of records.

Error: `Invalid operation:This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported yet;`

Using PostgreSQL and redshift.

My query:

```
select event_id, domain_userid, collector_tstamp, se_category, se_action, se_label, se_property,
CASE WHEN serp_flag = 0 THEN 0
     WHEN serp_flag = 1 THEN 1
     WHEN serp_flag is null then (select serp_flag from (select t2.serp_flag,(t1.collector_tstamp - t2.collector_tstamp) as time_diff from temp.serp_funnel t2
          where t1.domain_userid = t2.domain_userid and (t1.collector_tstamp - t2.collector_tstamp) >= 0 and t2.serp_flag is not null order by time_diff limit 1))
END
from temp.serp_funnel t1
limit 100;
```

This is how my table(part of it) looks

```
|------------|----------------|--------------|
|domainid    |timestamp       |serp_flag     |
|------------|----------------|--------------|
|d1          |t1              |1             |
|------------|----------------|--------------|
|d1          |t2              |null          |
|------------|----------------|--------------|
|d1          |t3              |null          |
|------------|----------------|--------------|
|d1          |t4              |0             |
|------------|----------------|--------------|
|d1          |t5              |null          |
|------------|----------------|--------------|
```

This is what I want

```
|------------|----------------|--------------|
|domainid    |timestamp       |serp_flag     |
|------------|----------------|--------------|
|d1          |t1              |1             |
|------------|----------------|--------------|
|d1          |t2              |1             |
|------------|----------------|--------------|
|d1          |t3              |1             |
|------------|----------------|--------------|
|d1          |t4              |0             |
|------------|----------------|--------------|
|d1          |t5              |0             |
|------------|----------------|--------------|
```

Also timestamp is sorted for each domain user.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `lag()` with the `ignore null`s option:

```
select t.*,
       lag(serp_flag ignore nulls) over (partition by domainid order by timestamp)
from t;
```

But, Postgres doesn't support that (yet?).  Then, you might think:  "hey, let's use `filter`":

```
select t.*
       lag(serp_flag) filter (where serp_flag is not null) over (partition by domainid order by timestamp
from t;
```

And that doesn't work either.  So, here is a method that uses two steps.  First a `max()` on `timestamp` and then a `max()` over that for `serp_flag`:

```
select t.*, max(serp_flag) over (partition by domainid, grp)
from (select t.*,
             max(case when serp_flag is not null then timestamp end) over (partition by domainid order by timestamp) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

I can't readily think of a way to do it in one step.

I should of course note that this is readily done with a subquery or lateral join:

```
select t.*, tt.serp_code
from t left join lateral
     (select t.*
      from t tt
      where tt.domainid = t.domainid and
            tt.timestamp <= t.timestamp and
            tt.serp_flag is not null
      order by tt.timestamp desc
      limit 1
     ) tt;
```

This should even have decent performance with an index on `t(domainid, timestamp, serp_flag)`.

Comment: @Gordan Linoff 
I added `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` as I was getting `Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause` error. Now, query working fine except places when collector_tstamp of two events are equal

Comment: @KumarVivek . . . More recent versions of Postgres don't need the windowing clause.  Also, you can handle the equality cases by including a primary key to distinguish the ordering.

Comment: @Gordan. .Thank you for your valuable suggestion and help in the query. Will use primary key to distinguish the ordering.